# Show screenshot preview with bounding boxes from lighthouse report

Tags: reactjs, screenshot, bounding-box, lighthouse

given the following lighthouse report:
https://hpj2wy.csb.app/lighthouse.html

I want to display the boundingboxes of the error elements in a similar way, but within a react component.

Here is what I have so far, the first few previews are working fine, but the others do not. I dont know why. Can you help me to show them correctly, please?

Editor demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-snow-hpj2wy

The bounding boxes are taken from the accessibility ->  Background and foreground colors do not have a sufficient contrast ratio. - Rule